Prove: Let $\{k_{1}, k_{2}, \dots ,k_{j}\}$ be a list of positive integers that sum to $ n $ (i.e., $ \sum_{i=1}^j k_i = n $
Let $\{k_{1}, k_{2}, \dots, k_{j}\}$ be a list of positive integers that sum to $ n $ (i.e., $ \sum_{i=1}^j k_i = n $ . I am trying to prove the following inequality:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^j \binom{k_i}{2} \leq \binom{n}{2}
$$
The hint that accompanies the problem is:
"How many edges does $  K_n  $ have? One of the two graphs will not be connected (unless $ j = 1$)."
I understand that the complete graph $ K_n $ has $  \binom{n}{2}  $ total edges, but I am not sure how to relate this to the sum of the binomial coefficients on the left-hand side of the inequality. Can anyone offer a detailed explanation or point me in the right direction for proving this inequality?
Do we divide by 2, as in $n(n−1)/2$ total edges. How do we use this to show that it is greater than the LHS? thank you!

@Gary is it possible to prove it not combinatorially?

@Glo I have added an algebraic proof in the dupe.
